# XmlSchemaException: Top-level attributes may not have a 'use'

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, weblogic, cxf

I've generated a webservice from the wsdl using maven `cxf-codegen-plugin`. This was fine and I got no exceptions. 
Then I attempted to instantiate the webservice using this code(Service class is generated):

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setEndpointName(SERVICE_NAME);
    factory.setAddress("https://someadress:port/spec");
    factory.setServiceClass(Service.class);
    this.port = (Service) factory.create();
```

On calling the create method, I receive the following exception when running on weblogic:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Top-level attributes may not have a 'use'
    ...
Caused By: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Top-level attributes may not have a 'use'
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaAttribute.setUse(XmlSchemaAttribute.java:109)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleAttribute(SchemaBuilder.java:966)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1519)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:497)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:483)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection.read(SchemaCollection.java:133)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument(AbstractDataBinding.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:393)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:697)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
```

AFIAK, the wsdl is not referenced anywhere in the initialization of the webservice and I would assume that when the classes were successfully generated, the webservice is generated from the valid source.

Anyway I don't have a clue what does the message mean. Yes, I've found this single link on the internet concerning the issue: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Schema-validation-errors-on-publish-quot-top-level-elements-may-not-have-a-use-quot-td5724860.html
but I still have no idea what is wrong.

Another thing is, that I'm not quite sure what is the definition of top-level attribute. I googled "xml top level attribute", but on the first two pages of results, there's no definition.

So I've searched the XSDs referenced from wsdl and found some things containing "use="in the opengis gml and one othe XSD:

```
<complexType name="UnitOfMeasureType">
    <sequence/>
    <attribute name="uom" type="gml:UomIdentifier" use="required"/>
</complexType>
```

and also this:

```
<attributeGroup name="extendedLink">
    <attribute name="type" type="string" fixed="extended" form="qualified"/>
    <attribute ref="xlink:role" use="optional"/>
    <attribute ref="xlink:title" use="optional"/>
</attributeGroup>
```

Is some of these things a problem?

The webservice works when I run it from the unit test, but not when deployed on Weblogic.

I use:

- Apache CXF 2.6.11
- Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0
- Oracle Java 1.7.0_25

Answer (score 1):

The recent versions of Weblogic use MOXy as their JAXB implementation instead of the JAXB 
reference implementation or the implementation built into the JDK.   If this is working outside of Weblogic, it's likely a problem in MOXy.  The CXF team has found several bugs in MOXy's schema generations (and other areas).   The good news is that the MOXy team is usually fairly prompt in fixing any issue that are found.   If you can distill this down to a small test case, that could be a big help.

Comment: In JUnit test and in Tomcat 7 it is fine, so your explanation seems reasonable. Do you have by any chance some idea for possible workaround?