# CXF Webservice client breaks when providing wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, weblogic, cxf

I've created a webservice client using cxf-codegen maven plugin and then instantiate the service like this:

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setEndpointName(SERVICE_NAME);
    factory.setAddress("some address");
    factory.setServiceClass(Service.class);
    this.port = (Service) factory.create();
```

It all works fine and I can call the webservice. But I have a problem running this on Weblogic([XmlSchemaException: Top-level attributes may not have a 'use'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117215/xmlschemaexception-top-level-attributes-may-not-have-a-use)) and as a possible solution I'm trying to provide the WSDL file so that it's not regenerated. 
But when I add the wsdl:

```
factory.setWsdlLocation("service.wsdl");
```

I get this exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not find definition for port {namespace}Service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:428)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
```

I cannot modify the wsdl and I'd like to know how is it possible, that the service construction fails if I provide the wsdl the service was generated from.

I use CXF 2.6.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need a factory.setServiceName(...) call in there as well to match the WSDL.

Comment: I don't quite understand what should I provide there(it expects a QName). The factory already has the physical address of the webservice and endpointname referring to the namespace and port.

Comment: I removed ```setEndpointName``` and added ```setServiceName``` with the same QName and now it works. Thanks. I guess the problem in my case is, that the physical URL doesn't match the namespace from wsdl